# How to get notified when alert appeared in webpage using java with selenium >

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate a website, but there is sudden appearance of alert box which is related some feed back which i need to close that alert then only i can proceed to new level in that site.
The problem is i am unable to find the alert box appears at particular time in that site. it appears randomly.
How to solve my problem.

Comment: You can't notify when alert comes but you can block it which will never come during execution. Is this good for you??

Comment: @Saurbh Gaur: What do you mean by blocking? How to achieve that? I was thinking about second thread to check if alert appear... (this is not my problem, but sound interesting)

Comment: how to block that alert will never come during execution.

Comment: Ya sure, I have provided it as an answer try it and let me know..:)

Answer (score 3):

The fastest solution I can think up is to create a method **onAlert()** that will get rid of the alert, something like

```
try{
    Alert alert = null;
    try {   
        alert = driver.switchTo().alert();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(27);
        robot.keyRelease(27);
    }

    if (alert != null) {
        alert.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

After that, you just have to call it within your code every time. I know this is not the best implementation, but it will work.

Comment: I think OP has no problem with dismiss alert, but the problem is alert can appear suddenly, and dont know when run the code

Comment: In that case, 
while(!finished) {
   try {
    * Your code here *
    //If done, set finished = true
   } catch (Exception e) {
       alert.dismiss();
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block unnecessary alert appearance during execution, you need to override alert function using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.alert = function() { return true; }");
```

You should just run the above mentioned code once at every time when new page loading before doing other action. It will override the alert functionally and accept it internally.

**Edited** :- As you're saying it's a `HTML` alert window instead of `JavaScript` alert then above code wouldn't work, in this case you should hide this alert using `JavascriptExecutor` once at every time when new page loading before doing other stuff if it is found as below :

```
//find first alert element 
List<WebElement> alert = driver.findElements(..);
if(alert.size() > 0 && alert.get(0).isDisplayed())
{ 
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'none'", alert.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Its not working i am facing  the same error again. i have placed this line at when new page loading but same error.

Comment: Ok first make sure it's `window.alert` or something else?? To make sure go to browser console by pressing f12 and execute this script `window.alert = function() { return true; }` and do some operation on page and see alert open or not but be sure page is same that time

Comment: Actually i am unable to find whether it is alert or not it is like webpage having id's and classes. I have successfully closed that alert using try catch i have clicked on NO button in that alert window using "xpath" in catch block but need to resume the code after closing the window,  So i am able to close the window using "xpath"  but unable to find when it appears exactly.

Comment: That means it's not a JavaScript Alert... Right??

Comment: Yes it contains html code only.It is like site survey, when that window appears back-end web page is blocked with shade until click on that window or close that window .

Comment: Then you need to find this alert using findElements with appropriate locator and if it's  present use JavascriptExecutor to hide this alert before doing other stuff...try with edited answer and let me know...:)

Comment: Using your updated answer i am able to find that alert is appeared at which line but unable to close the alert using the code u have given inside if statement.

Comment: Are you getting whole alert box element or only getting close button element??

Comment: I am getting close button element only .How to get whole alert box element .Alert appears two types one is with close button i have found that button xapth and placed in driver.findElements(By.xpath("buttonxpath"));
and another one is without close button some no,Thanks button in that alert i have placed the same in driver.findElements(By.xpath("no'thanksbuttonxpath"));

Comment: Yes but it would be present inside any element, you need to inspect whole box of alert and provide that locator..if you not able to identify need to share here HTML for alert box, that's why I could give you correct locator..:)

Comment: Saurabh tq your logic worked for me by using findelements i have created two lists one is for close button another one is for no'thanks button placed in one method and called that method when page changes.it worked fine.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur When javascript pop-up appears on my web application, O opened the console and typed window.alert = function() { return true; }  but the pop-up window didn't disappear. Does that mean that it wasn't a javascript nature of the window?

Comment: If alert already popuped then this function does not work because popup already executed, you meed to execute before popuped then you will see if its actual js alret it wouldn't popup..

Answer (score 1):

Declare the global variable eg:

```
public boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
```

Following is the function

```
public String closeAlertAndGetItsText() 
 {
        try {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String alertText = alert.getText();
          if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
          } else {
            alert.dismiss();
          }
          return alertText;
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException ex)
         { 
           ex.printStackTrace();
         }
        finally 
        {
          acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
        return StartUrl;
      }
}
```

Call this function

```
String c=closeAlertAndGetItsText();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution based on Saurabh's code

```
  List<WebElement> alert = driver.findElements(..);
    if(alert.size() > 0 && alert.get(0).isDisplayed())
    { 
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'none'", alert.get(0));
    }
```

I have created class CloseAlert.java in my project and inside the class created a static method closeAlert.
created two list for the elements which are in appeared alert box and called this class in my main class when ever the new page is opened and it works fine now.

```
 public class CloseAlert {
        static List<WebElement> alert;
        static List<WebElement> alert2;

        public static void AlertClose(WebDriver driver)
        {
            alert = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='fsrCloseBtn']"));
            alert2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='fsrDeclineButtonContainer']/a"));

            if(alert.size() > 0 && alert.get(0).isDisplayed()||alert2.size() > 0 && alert2.get(0).isDisplayed())
            { 
                if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fsrDeclineButtonContainer']/a")).isDisplayed())
                {
                    System.out.println("Alert found with no thanks button");

                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fsrDeclineButtonContainer']/a")).click();
                }
                else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='fsrCloseBtn']")).isDisplayed())
                {
                    System.out.println("alert found with Close button" );
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='fsrCloseBtn']")).click();
                }

            }

            }
```